# Extract a string between 2 characters of the same character

Tags: java, string

I understand how to extract a string between 2 DIFFERENT types of strings like [ and ], or ( ), etc...

But what I don't know is how to get multiple/all strings between 1 character.
Eg:

```
the *big* brown fox *jumps over* the *lazy* **dog**
```

it should return for "*":

```
big
jumps over
lazy
```

and it should also return for "**":

```
dog
```

All libraries, regex patterns and such don't support such a feature.

Comment: Within a loop, use `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: Create your own method that respects your conditions and build your output strings with stringbuilder

Comment: you need regexp matching with a groups like "(\*\w+\*)" and "(\*\*\w+\*\*)" See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508965/java-regexp-group-capturing

Answer (score 5):

This regex :

```
[\*]+([a-z ]*)[\*]+
```

will match what you are looking for. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/oV5dM7/1).

- `[\*]+` at the end matches 1 or more `*`s.
- `([a-z ]*)` matches the characters between a-z and the space, and returns that.

Now since Andy turner points out that it also matches `dog` in `*dog*********`, You can do:

```
[\*]{1,2}([a-z ]*)[\*]{1,2}
```

This would match `*`s between 1 and 2. (See [this](https://regex101.com/r/wT7xB7/4)) You can change that to any range, but note that `{1,3}` will match 1,2 or 3 times, and not only 1 and 3 times.

Comment: This doesn't quite work - it doesn't match the same start and end. For instance, it would match `*dog**********` (and for `**dog**` it would match `**` and `**`).

Comment: @AndyTurner You are right. But that wasn't a requirement. Was it?

Comment: @AndyTurner No. for `**dog**`. It would match `dog` Seen the link?

Comment: @MilanvanDijck No it doesn't. `[\*]+` tries to match as many `*`s as possible. So, they are already gone. we only return the part between `(` and `)`

Comment: Oh, OK. But it does match `*dog**********`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, but OP doesn't say that it shouldn't.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="the *big* brown fox *jumps over* the *lazy* **dog**"    
str = str.replace("**", "*");
```

and then perform the extraction method you were using

Comment: There is a more elegant way to solve it (with regular expressions) but this is not wrong and should not be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "the *big* brown fox *jumps over* the *lazy* **dog**";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(test,"*");

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```